# MySql Error: field is ambiguos (code 1052)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a SELECT statement that will be able to extract data from various tables according to certain conditions but i keep getting the same error "Error Code 1052: Column Username in where clause is ambiguouse"

Here is the sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM engineer, users WHERE Username = "James" AND Password = "12345"
```

Here is what the tables involved look like

engineer: user_id(pk), Username, Password, Address, Contact_No

users: user_id(pk), Username, Password, Address, Contact_No

I think the error might be in that there is the same Username column in both table but i can't find a proper sql statement that would work.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Also, why do you have two tables with exactly the same columns?  This is usually a sign of a problem with the data model.

Comment: It means both your tables contain a column with the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the syntax table.column_name. So your query can be:

```
SELECT * FROM engineer, users WHERE engineer.Username = 'James' AND engineer.Password = '12345'
```

I choose engineer but you can do the same with users or mix the two. Also note the single quotes around the values.

Comment: he also need apply the conditions on users table (or use ON clause), to achieve expected result.

Comment: You are right. My answer was just focused on explaining the reason of the error op was facing. Not enough information to build an optimized query IMHO

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM engineer WHERE Username = "James" AND Password = "12345"
UNION
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = "James" AND Password = "12345"
;
```